# Who owns a dog?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So recently, I made an [adventure map](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/552293-adv-trantorvs-now-available-to-all/page__p__7360463__fromsearch__1#entry7360463). While I was building it, I came across a pack of wolves, so I tamed them, and sat them down around the map, so that the player who discovered them would get a bit of help.

However, I've had reports that players can't 'unsit' the dogs. Is this because they are linked to my Minecraft account and will only obey my commands? I had assumed they automatically belonged to the person playing the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [entity format](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Alpha_Level_Format/Chunk_File_Format#Mobs) used to store mob state in the chunks has bonus fields for wolves that include:

> - TAG_String(**"Owner"**): Name of the player that owns this wolf. Empty string if no owner.

I'm trying to figure out how to decompress the chunk file format and see if your name pops up in one of them, but it might take a little work.